# UIScrollView filling is slow

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have in my iOS7+ app this paginated `UIScrollView` that for every page contains a `UIView` that contains a single `UITextView`.

This is the code that fills it.

```
// Looping through results
for(int i = 0; i < [data count]; i++) {
    // Creating view
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i * scrollSize.width, 0, scrollSize.width, scrollSize.height)];

    // Creating the UITextView
    UITextView *theText = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollSize.width * 0.9, scrollSize.height * 0.5)];
    theText.backgroundColor = nil;
    theText.scrollEnabled = NO;
    theText.selectable    = NO;
    theText.center = CGPointMake(view.frame.size.width / 2, view.frame.size.height / 2);

    // Assigning properties
    theText.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[data objectAtIndex:i] attributes:attribute];

    // Centering the label and assigning font size
    theText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:FONT_NAME size:fontSize];
    theText.textColor = FONT_COLOR;

    // Adding label to view and view to scrollView
    [view addSubview:theText];
    [scroll addSubview:view];
}
```

It's pretty slow, blocking the UI of the app. (around 0.38sec for `data` of 30 element).

I'm trying to optimize it by not creating every time the subviews, but looks like I can't copy the original object.

How can I make it faster? Can I reuse some elements in the loop? Should I user something like `UICollectionView`? Will the `UICollectionView` fit my needs?

Thanks!

Comment: The typical approach is only to create the views to the left/right of the view that is visible and create the next one as it scrolls. You can also reuse the three views by resetting content and resetting the scroll view offset once scrolling is complete.

Comment: Uh, looks neat! I'll give it a try! Any example out there? :D

Comment: I know that is out of topic but have you tried icarousel framework?

Comment: Apple also have sample code and a WWDC session from a couple of years ago on scroll views and paging, but yes carouselview is what I often use